# Static List of items in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using `Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33)` and I'm attempting to add a static List with items. I was able to compile my project only once and it did in fact work just fine, now I'm getting some strange errors. I made a simple code example below and even that is giving me the same error I'm seeing in my other project. Am I missing something simple or?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Item 1")
            Text("Item 2")
            Text("Item 3")
        }
    }
}
```

`Return type of property 'body' requires that 'List' conform to 'View'`

`Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'List' conform to 'View'`

`Trailing closure passed to parameter of type Decoder that does not accept a closure.`

Comment: All is fine with Xcode 12.4. Are you sure you did not redeclare List anywhere in project (maybe model)?

Comment: No, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you declared your own type called Liat?

Comment: Going to try Xcode 12.4. It may have been a minor error in my list style in my other project, I'll see after Xcode installs.

Answer (score 1):

**List Code in SWIFTUI***

```
struct RestRow: View {
var name: String
var body: some View {
    Text("Restaurant: \(name)")
}
}

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    List {
        RestRow(name: "ITEM # 1")
        RestRow(name: "ITEM # 2")
        RestRow(name: "ITEM # 3")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is the same code as in the question, why?

Comment: I found the solution. I had List redeclared elsewhere in my `Codable` data. Apparently unrelated lol but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my JSON data had a redeclared List.. My JSON data is pretty extensive, very embarrassing to miss that.